# Regex get only numeric values from string

Tags: regex, vb.net

I want to get **116.83** and **81.16** from the below string. I tried **\d** but it also selects 2 from **up2** and **dn2**. How can i ignore this.

```
<td align="right">
    116.83<span class="up2"></span><br>81.16<span class="dn2"></span>
</td>
```

Comment: What characters are allowed to come before and after the number?

Comment: if you want to parse HTML, don't use regular expressions, use a DOM parser.

Comment: What language? Why not use a proper parser?

Comment: The value is out of span tag. How can i parse the data.

Comment: @JanDvorak Its Visual Basic

Comment: @Santosh get all text nodes of the `td`.

Comment: In the javascript DOM API, that is `nodes = [].filter.call(elem.childNodes, function(x){return x.nodeType==3})`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\b[\d.]+\b
```

`\b` matches the boundary between word and non-word characters, but doesn't include the adjacent characters in the match. Since letters and numbers are both word characters, it won't match between `p` and `2`, so `up2` doesn't match. But `>` is a non-word character, so it matches between `>` and `8`, therefore the regexp matches `81.16`.

Comment: Its what i wanted. Thanks you very much. Can you also explain. I have accepted/voted your answer.

Comment: I did explain. What part don't you understand?

Comment: @Barmar - Did you mean to escape the period? `\b[\d\.]+\b`

Comment: @Aiias No, period has no special meaning inside `[]`, so it doesn't need to be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
[>\s]+([\d\.]+)[<\s]+
```

But be sure to strip the leading `>` and whitespace as well as the trailing `<` and whitespace from the first level match OR take the second level matches only.

Comment: You should be using the value from capture group 1, which gets what's in the parentheses.