# Regex VBA Match

Tags: html, regex, vba, excel, xml-parsing

How can i get the value 81.16 in second msgbox?
[Regex get only numeric values from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847939/regex-get-only-numeric-values-from-string)

```
Sub Tests()
    Const strTest As String = "<td align=""right"">116.83<span class=""up2""></span><br>81.16<span class=""dn2""></span></td>"
    RE6 strTest
End Sub



Function RE6(strData As String) As String
    Dim RE As Object, REMatches As Object

    Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With RE
        ' .MultiLine = True
        '.Global = False
        .Pattern = "\b[\d.]+\b"
    End With

    Set REMatches = RE.Execute(strData)
    MsgBox REMatches(0)
    MsgBox REMatches(1)    'getting error here
End Function
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**First of all, try not to use RegEx to parse any kind of xml. Try using xml parsers or  [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath)**

> **XPath**, the XML Path Language, is a query language for selecting nodes
>   from an XML document. In addition, XPath may be used to compute values
>   (e.g., strings, numbers, or Boolean values) from the content of an XML
>   document.

### To solve your problem change

```
'.Global = False 'Matches only first occurrence
```

Into

```
.Global = True 'Matches all occurrences
```

### How to properly parse XML in VBA:

Please note that I had to close your `<br />` tag to be valid.

```
Private Sub XmlTestSub()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim xml As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim nodes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim node As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

    yourXmlString = "<td align=""right"">116.83<span class=""up2""></span><br />81.16<span class=""dn2""></span></td>"

    Set xml = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    If (Not xml.LoadXML(yourXmlString)) Then
        Err.Raise xml.parseError.ErrorCode, "XmlTestSub", xml.parseError.reason
    End If

    Set nodes = xml.SelectNodes("/td/text()") 'XPath Query

    For Each node In nodes
        Debug.Print node.NodeValue
    Next node

Done:
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume Done

End Sub
```